# Filtros de busquedas en php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Me da error en la linea 124

Warning: Undefined variable $mysql_fetch_assoc in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema_escuela\duenio\consultar_clases.php on line 124

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Value of type null is not callable in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema_escuela\duenio\consultar_clases.php:124 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema_escuela\duenio\consultar_clases.php on line 124

```
if(isset($_POST['boton-filtrar'])) {
        $materias = $_POST['materia'];
        $alumnos = $_POST['alumno'];
        $anio_desde = $_POST['anio-desde'];
        $anio_hasta = $_POST['anio-hasta'];
        $profesores = $_POST['profesor'];
        $estado = $_POST['estado'];
    
    
    $sql = mysqli_query("SELECT m.nombre, prof.nombre,cla.fecha_dictado, cla.estado 
                    from clases cla
                        inner join materias m ON cla.materia_id = m.id
                        inner join usuarios alum on  cla.alumno_id = alum.id
                        inner join usuarios prof on  cla.profesor_id = prof.id 
                    where 
                        1=1
                        AND m.nombre = '$materias' 
                        AND alum.nombre = '$alumnos'
                        AND prof.nombre = '$profesores'
                        AND cla.fecha_dictado between date'2022-04-03' and date'2023-09-04'
                        AND cla.estado = '$estado'");

    $guardado4 = $conexion->query($sql);

<table class="table">
                            <?php while($rowSql = $mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){ ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-center">Materia</td><?php echo $rowSql['nombre']?>
                                    <td class="text-center">Profesor</td><?php echo $rowSql['nombre']?>
                                    <td class="text-center">Fecha</td><?php echo $rowSql['fecha_dictado']?>
                                    <td class="text-center">Estado</td><?php echo $rowSql['estado']?>
                                <tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedo observar en tu código es un tema mas de errores sintácticos que otra cosa.
Lo primero si tu código es tal como lo pusiste, entonces te falta cerrar el primer `IF`, otro punto es que si usas mysqli_query te falta el conector

```php
if ($resultado = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT Name FROM City LIMIT 10")) {
    printf("La selección devolvió %d filas.\n", mysqli_num_rows($resultado));

    /* liberar el conjunto de resultados */
    mysqli_free_result($resultado);
}
```

Otro punto es `$mysql_fetch_assoc`, la estas usando como variable al setearla con $, siendo que es una palabra reservada de php ya que corresponde a `mysql_fetch_assoc` la cual ademas se encuentra obsoleta ya hace varios años, ahora se usa `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.